# json dumps large list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dump

I am trying to save a large list of dictionaries (above 100,000) as a json file by means of 'json.dumps'.

The code runs without errors, but unfortunately it does not manage to save the full list. I get something like a cropped file.

Interestingly, if I try to save a shorter list of the same dictionaries (e.g. 10,000) everything goes smoothly. Does anyone have any idea of the reason behind that?

I created this example with a few lines of code to save a list 'test' of 'dict_example' into the json file called 'scenario'. In my case, it would save a file with just a few thousands elements.

```
test=[]
for i in range(200000):
    pass
    dict_example={}
    dict_example['guid']=i
    dict_example['info']={}
    dict_example['info']['color']='red'
    dict_example['info']['location'] = random.randint(1,10000)
    dict_example['info']['day'] = random.randint(1,10000)


    test.append(dict_example)


with open(os.path.join(output_directory,'orders'+scenario), "w") as f:
    json.dump(test,f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

My corrupted output json file would look like a cropped list as shown below:
[image: cropped list of dict]

Comment: try `json.dump(list_of_dicts, f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)` might work better since it lets the json library do the io

Comment: That's weird, I'm pretty sure it should not happen. Can you add code that generates enough data to trigger this behaviour on your system? It doesn't have to be the actual data you'd like to write, just something other people can test with (see [mcve]).

Comment: @Macattack already tried with that, but keep having the same issue

Comment: TIL of that [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) (without the s) variant. Very cool @Macattack.

Comment: @Norrius Just added an example.

Comment: other things that might be useful - python version and an example of the corruption/ incorrect end of the list

Comment: @msanford there's `load` and `loads` too, same for the `pickle` library, likely some other examples too I'm just not thinking of

Comment: @Macattack added a sreenshot of the corrupted file I am getting, as you can see, it looks cropped at a random point. I am using Python 3.7

Comment: And what platform are you on? You might try splitting it up into multiple writes, but, you should be getting some error since it's apparently failing to write, it doesn't make sense that there is no error, could you be out of disk space? Maybe try something dumb like write 1 character at a time or write in chunks?

Comment: @Macattack I just tested it, and at least on Linux, no free space does produce a cut-off file like this. It raises an exception (`OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`), but depending on how OP runs the code, it might be suppressed. I guess it's either that or the file editor is borked (easily checkable with `cat my.json | tail` on Unix/Linux).

Comment: @Norrius file editor problems also occurred to me. Could just open the file for reading and json decode it right after writing it, see if it decodes properly. Also, `tail my.json` ;) vastly more efficient for large files than catting it to tail.